# Is there a function to check if a string value be converted to number?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom field called value__c in my custom object.
This field can store values which could be a string, number, decimal or currency.

How can i check if this particular value can be converted to number,decimal or currency?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use some of the new String methods, for example isNumeric.
Are you in a situation where you don't know in advance what kind of data will be in the string?
You can use try and catch around attempted conversions, eg.

```
try {
  Integer x = Integer.valueOf(myString);
}
Catch (exception e) {
  // it's not an Integer, try something else
}
```

Comment: isNumeric for the win :) But it won't process decimals so proper order of try catching should be Decimal -> Long -> isNumeric -> give up, it's a string

Comment: Nice to be able to use some of the new Winter13 String methods

Comment: thats correct. I dont know which format it is, basically the field of string type but if there are numeric values then i would need to do some summing up. The design is a little crazy :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about Apex, but in most languages, try/catch blocks are not efficient to run (they have a lot of processor overhead).  So `if(test)` methods are generally preferable to try/catch methods, especially inside a loop.

I know Apex doesn't have an `isNumeric()` method that recognizes the decimal point, but we can use the `replaceFirst()` method to remove just a single decimal point, then run `isNumeric()` on the remaining string:

```
if(myString.replaceFirst('.', '').isNumeric())
    myDecimal = decimal.valueOf(myString);
```

Comment: Minor correction in the syntax of above code. We need to put decimal sign in a regular expression format i.e. within square bracket otherwise it will convert 123.45 to 23.45. 
if(myString.replaceFirst('[.]','').isNumeric().isNumeric())
    myDecimal = decimal.valueOf(myString);

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Integer.valueOf and the instanceof constructs to achieve this (primitives also being objects in apex helps !)

```
    try{
    object  m = Integer.valueOf('123');
    System.debug(m instanceof integer);   //returns true if integer, false otherwise
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        // if not integer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the below class for your use. You can extend this for boolean, decimal. & datetime.

```
public class Convert{
    public class IntResult{
       public Boolean IsValid{ get; private set; }
       public Integer Value { get; private set; }
       public IntResult(Boolean pIsValid, Integer pValue){
           IsValid = pIsValid;
           Value = pValue;
       }
       public IntResult(Boolean pIsValid){
           IsValid = pIsValid;
           Value = null;
       }
    }
    public static IntResult toInt(String strInput){
        IntResult result = null;
        try {
            Integer intValue = Integer.valueOf(strInput);
            result = new IntResult(true, intValue);
        }
        Catch (exception e) {
            result = new IntResult(false);
        }
        return result;
    }
    static testmethod void testConvert_toInt() {
        IntResult res1 = Convert.toInt('34');
        if(res1.IsValid){
            System.debug(res1.Value);
        }
        IntResult res2 = Convert.toInt('we');
        if(!res2.IsValid){
            System.debug('Invalid Value');
        }
     }
}
```